# how to manage the changing state of a player in a game?

Tags: python-2.7

I am making a simple text based game that uses a `while` loop for combat. It asks the player what they want to do and gives options to use weapons or inventory (potions and such). If they select inventory to see what they have, how can I give them the option to go back to select a weapon and attack instead? I tried to create a function called `back` with the only code for it being `pass`, that if the user typed in `back` it would send them to the beginning of the menu. But it would just endlessly loop the enemy's attack and not let the user do anything. Any ideas? Here is my combat code:

I want to be able to send them back to just after the `print "what will you do?"` line

```
 def combat():

    hero_hp = 1000000
    enemy_hp = randint(5, 10)
    enemy_name_test = randint(1,5) 
    enemy_weapon_test = randint(1,5)   
    enemy_name = list_of_enemys[enemy_name_test]
    enemy_weapon = list_of_weapons[enemy_weapon_test]
    while hero_hp > 0 and enemy_hp > 0:
        print "The %s swings at you with a %s" % (enemy_name, enemy_weapon)
        damage = randint(0, 10)
        if damage == 0 :
            print "the %s misses" %enemy_name
        else : 
            hero_hp -= damage
            print "The %s hits you with a %s for %d hit points you have %d hit points left" % (enemy_name, enemy_weapon, damage, hero_hp)
            hero_hp -= damage
        if hero_hp <= 0 :
            print "you have been slain!"
            close()
        else :  
            print "What will you do?"


        print inventory 
        player_choice = raw_input("> ") 
        if player_choice == '1' :
            print hero_weapons
            player_choice2 = raw_input("> ")
            weapon = hero_weapons[player_choice2]


            damage = randint(0, 10)
            enemy_hp -= damage
            print "You attack with %s for %d hit points" % (weapon, damage)
            print "%s has %d hit points left" % (enemy_name, enemy_hp)
            if enemy_hp <= 0 :
                print "You have slain the %s" % enemy_name 
            else :
                pass


        else :
            print hero_equipment
            player_choice2 = raw_input("> ")
            heal = randint(1, 10)
            hero_equipment.pop(player_choice2)
            print "you drink a potion and heal %s hit points" % heal
```

Comment: just curious what i did to get down voted? i want to avoid making the mistake again.

Comment: Someone felt that "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". If you make an effort to specify the question...about 'control statements'...it might be possible to figure it out yourself with a search engine or make it easier on others.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer doesn't shoot over your head, but your program is getting to a level of complexity that will soon turn it into a non-working mess.

I suggest you look into Finite State Machines which are a good way of gathering up

1. What my player is doing now
2. What the player's choices are from here
3. What new states each choice takes the player

Your code already describes an FSM, it just does it through a combination of if statements and choice variables. Here's a state table that's close to what you are trying describe with your code

```
              |choice
state         |attack        potion        inventory       back
--------------+--------------------------------------------------------
combat_begin  |combat_begin  combat_begin  show_inventory
show_inventory|              combat_begin                  combat_begin
```

If the player has begun combat, she can attack after which she goes to the start of combat. She can use a potion which also puts her back to combat_begin (and has whatever effect the potion does). She can ask to see her inventory which puts her in a new state (show_inventory). The one thing she can't do at the start of combat is go "back" because that cell is empty.

If the player is in show_inventory state, she can go "back" or use a potion, both of which starts combat again. What she can't do here is attack or show inventory.

Obviously I've made this example almost stupidly simple in hope of giving you an idea of where this needs to go.

Comment: Ok thank you i will look into finite state machines and see if i can figure it out. thanks for the nudge in the right direction i guess i did not know exactly what to look for to do what i want too.

Answer (score 0):

Create a speperate function with what you want looped in it, then whenever it is to be looped, call the function.

eg:

```
def example(example_item):
    if example_a == example_b:
        example(example_item) #calling the function again
    else: 
        return(false)
```

of course thats not what you would use, but its just an example.
make sure that each time around something changes or it will be an infinate loop. for example you could add `1` to `example_a`, which would eventualy stop the loop at some point.